# Adding tool tips to a d3 area chart

Tags: d3.js

Does anyone have an example or know how to add d3 tip to an area chart? I'm using a kind of stacked area chart.

```
let blockedGen = d3.svg.area()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.projectDate); })
            .y0(height)
            .interpolate("basis")
            .y1(function(d) { return y(d.done + d.review + d.inprogress + d.blocked ); });

        let todoGen = d3.svg.area()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.projectDate); })
            .y0(height)
            .interpolate("basis")
            .y1(function(d) { return y( d.done + d.review + d.inprogress + d.blocked + d.todo); });
var svg = d3.select(".demandChart").append("svg")
            .attr("id","demandchart")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let todoLayer =  svg.append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', todoGen(dataDemand))
            .attr("fill-opacity","1")
            .attr('fill', 'rgb(49, 130, 189)');

        let blockedLayer =  svg.append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', blockedGen(dataDemand))
            .attr("fill-opacity",".7")
            .attr('fill', 'rgb(158, 202, 225)');
```

Thanks

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579 , http://codepen.io/ashokgowtham/pen/LpnHe Please refer to help center on how to ask good questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thats a nice example but is there one where there isn't data points?

Answer (score 0):

Add `var div = d3.select("#toolTip");`

Add below code to your `svg`:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {      
      div.transition()      
       .style("opacity", .9);       
       div.html("Project Date: " +  d.projectDate)
       .style("left",  (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
       .style("top",  (d3.event.pageY) + "px"); 
    }).on("mouseout", function() {
            div.transition()        
            .duration(500)      
            .style("opacity", 0);});
```

Add this in the `css` file:

```
div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

Comment: which svg? this one var svg = d3.select(".demandChart").append("svg") or this one let todoLayer =  svg.append('svg:path')?

Comment: The later one that would be `let  todoLayer `